# doubt in foreach -php

Tags: php, loops, foreach

i have this code. Basically identifies if any position of array is empty or have an input equal a zero.

```
$fields = array("first", "second", "third");

function check($fields, $form) {
    foreach($fields as $field) {
        if(empty($form[$field]) || $form[$field] === 0) {
            echo 'empty';
            return false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

My doubt now, is , how i can do an echo for example to show the second position is empty?

with an if? `if ($form[$field][second])` ? i don't know if this is correct, or exists a better option
thanks

Comment: I believe what this question is asking, is how can the function indicate *which* position was empty (since this currently just returns true or false, not the offending position(s))

Comment: Just an FYI, `empty` tests for `false`, `null`, `0`, and an empty string. So your `|| ... === 0` is just redundant. If you want the value to be allowed to be `false` or `null` then remove the `empty` check. But both are definitely not needed.

Comment: @Chris thanks for clarify the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if `$field` is what you want to `echo` then just prepend it to 'is empty':

```
$fields = array("first", "second", "third");

function check($fields, $form)
{
    foreach($fields as $field)
    {
        if(empty($form[$field]))
        {
            echo $field.' is empty';
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

if you need the index value:

```
$fields = array("first", "second", "third");

function check($fields, $form)
{
    foreach($fields as $k=>$field)
    {
        if(empty($form[$field]))
        {
            echo $k.' is empty';
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

eventually if the aim is retrieve the empty position (if `check` returns `-1` then there are no empty positions):

```
$fields = array("first", "second", "third");
function check($fields, $form)
{
    foreach($fields as $k=>$field)
    {
        if(empty($form[$field]))
            return $k;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do something like the following:

```
if (empty($form[$field+1])) {
    echo 'Empty';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a recursive function like this:

```
function isEmpty($array){
    if(is_array($array)){
        foreach($array as $key=>$value){
            if(isEmpty($value) !== false) return $key;
        }
        return false;
    }else{
        if($array === 0 || empty($array)){
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

This will traverse the array as deep as it goes, and return the index where it found an empty position, or false if it did not find an empty position.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe I'm in totally wrongness, but why not :

```
if(empty($form[2]) || $form[2] === 0) {
  echo 'second element is empty';
}
```

If your question is 'How can I know at what index am I while doing a `foreach`', then the answer is that :

```
$fields = array("first", "second", "third");

function check($fields, $form) {
    foreach($fields as $i => $field) {
        if ( (empty($form[$field]) || $form[$field] === 0) && ($i == 2)) {
            echo '2n element is empty';
            return false; // no need to break; as you have returned something.
        }
    }
}
```